# What is the context menu keycode in QMK?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu

I am trying to define a keymap for the context menu in my [QMK](https://beta.docs.qmk.fm/) enabled keyboard ([Planck EZ](https://odysee.com/@DistroTube:2/the-planck-ez-keyboard.-47-keys-are-all:9)). Is there a specific keycode for the context menu?

I don't want to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, because it is not exactly the same (see ["Why does the Shift+F10 menu differ from the right-click menu?"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110809-00/?p=9943)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Context Menu keycode in QMK is `KC_APPLICATION` (alias `KC_APP`). It is the [Application Context Menu Keycode](https://beta.docs.qmk.fm/using-qmk/simple-keycodes/keycodes). If you're using [Oryx](https://configure.zsa.io/), the keycode is named "Application" there:

[image: Oryx Config with Application Keycode]

Comment: What is this [Oryx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oryx_(disambiguation)) you speak of? Do you have a reference?

Comment: OK, it is probably [this one](https://www.zsa.io/oryx).

Comment: I can confirm that is correct. I have updated the answer to include the URL for the tool. Thanks!